# How to pass value to confirmation popup from custom screen

Tags: acumatica

I need to fire Complete Order action of Production Order Maintenance screen from my custom screen, the issue is, when action is fired am getting an error saying, "Are you sure want to complete the order" this is the same confirmation message we get when we do from Production Order Maintenance screen as well, my question is, how we can avoid this popup or how i can pass value to this popup from my custom graph.

```
ProdMaintGraph.ProdMaintRecords.Current = ProdItem;
ProdMaintGraph.completeorder.Press();
```

Comment: The error message "Are you sure want to complete the order" doesn't exists in the system. It appears made up as it is not grammatically correct.

Comment: Is the error message coming from a customization? You aren't likely to get a proper answer if that's the case because we don't have the source code of that customization.

Comment: Think I found it, the exact message is "Are you sure you want to complete the production order?" It is inside the Advanced Manufacturing Customization. It is coming from JAMS.DLL and is located in JAMS.AM.Messages.ConfirmCompleteMessage. I think this DLL was developed by JAAS Systems, maybe they will chime in with a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try it like this!

```
ProdMaintGraph.ProdMaintRecords.Cache.Graph.Views["ProdMaintRecords"].Answer = WebDialogResult.Yes;
```

If in the popup form Message Buttoin is `Yes`, or one is this values which are `None,OK ,Cancel,Abort,Retry ,Ignore,Yes,No`

Comment: Excellent method, it just occurred to me this could be used to read the value of the answer in scenario where the dialog code is inaccessible if the value sticks around in that variable.