# How to suppress customer class update

Tags: acumatica

My custom graph will create a new customer.  The new customer will not use a default customer class.  Each time my method saves the Customer record, the base event CustomerClass_FieldVerifying happens.  That event expects a user input, in order to accept & update the billing settings.  In my case, always the new customer should accept the billing setting updates.  I believe that I can override the base event, and simply step over:

```
if (BAccount.Ask(Messages.Warning, Messages.CustomerClassChangeWarning, MessageButtons.YesNo) == WebDialogResult.No)
```

I'm curious if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the answer in some way following this post:
[How to pass value to confirmation popup from custom screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56360479/how-to-pass-value-to-confirmation-popup-from-custom-screen/56365751#56365751)

Sample:

```
BAccount.Answer = WebDialogResult.Yes;
```